# How to deal with related and computed fields in Transient Models in Odoo 8?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I have a problem which I am not able to understand. I have added two new fields to the model `stock.production.lot`. These fields are computed floats, and work perfect. Their names are `current_qty` and `expected_qty`.

Then, I have created a Transient Model. In this one, I created a many2one field `lot_id` which points to the model `stock.production.lot`. And I have added two float fields, also named `current_qty` and `expected_qty`, which are related to the respective ones I mentioned above.

The problem is that only `current_qty` is getting the right value (the other one gets always zero).

Example:

I create a lot. When I do this, `current_qty` is computed and values 10.000, and `expected_qty` is computed too and values 5.000.

Now I open the Transient Model, and `current_qty` gets 10.000, which is right, but `expected_qty` gets False. Why?

Even I have added other field to the Transient Model. This one is a computed char which should show the next: *current_qty (expected_qty)*, following the values of this example, it should be *10.000 (5.000)*. But it also takes False value (it does not write the `current_qty` neither). Besides, I write log messages inside the compute method to check if the method is called and which values it takes. And surprisingly, the values of `current_qty` and `expected_qty` shown in the log are right! (10.000 and 5.000).

**Python code**

```
class ProductLotAvailable(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'product.lot.available'

    @api.multi
    @api.depends('current_qty', 'expected_qty')
    def _compute_beautiful_qty(self):
        for available_lot in self:
            current_qty = str(available_lot.current_qty)
            _logger.info(current_qty)
            expected_qty = str(available_lot.expected_qty)
            _logger.info(expected_qty)
            available_lot.beautiful_qty = current_qty + '(' + expected_qty + ')'

    lot_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='stock.production.lot',
        string='Lot',
        readonly=True,
    )
    current_qty = fields.Float(
        related='lot_id.current_qty',
        string='Current lot quantity',
        readonly=True,
        digits=dp.get_precision('Product Unit of Measure'),
    )
    expected_qty = fields.Float(
        related='lot_id.expected_qty',
        string='Expected lot quantity',
        readonly=True,
        digits=dp.get_precision('Product Unit of Measure'),
    )
    beautiful_qty = fields.Char(
        compute='_compute_beautiful_qty',
        string='Current lot quantity',
        readonly=True,
    )
```

**XML code**

```
<field name="product_lots_available" nolabel="1">
    <tree create="false" delete="false" editable="bottom">
        <field name="current_qty" invisible="0"/>
        <field name="expected_qty" invisible="0"/>
        <field name="beautiful_qty"/>
        <field name="lot_id"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

Can anyone help me with this? It is possible that there is a simple error in my code which I was not able to see for the last hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem: I had another module installed which was overwriting the method which loads the default values for the Transient Model. This method was filling in the `current_qty`, but not the `expected_qty`. And same problem with `beautiful_qty`.

So despite I was introducing the values I needed, they were being overwritten by the other module.

Answer (score 3):

The only reason what I am thinking is because it's related fields, so the value in that field will be placed only after you save that record. And because this model is transient model so wizard is getting opened but you can't open the same record again to verify that result.

To verify it if go to the database and check the record you will get the value there. For double sure just keep those both fields functional Store=False, so value will always be there.

I didn't found any other problem in your code.

Comment: Thank you! I have to mention that the wizard is filled in before being opened (through a context with `default_` keys), and I do not allow the user to create or delete records. So the record is saved and the related should be shown, shouldn't it? By the way, I set `store=False` in the computed fields, but same result. I could understand that neither of them work, but I cannot understand why `current_qty` works and `expected_qty` does not work, both of them are similar!!